# Django - Access Parent Model field when creating many-to-one model

Tags: django, model, parent-child, many-to-one

Imagine you have a model which is a book/web comic/cartoon for online reading:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/ + name + /coverImage/')
    ...
```

Then a model for each Chapter:

```
class Chapter(models.Model):
    book= models.ForeignKey('Book', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    date_released = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    date_changed = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Then you have the child model which will contain the images for each page:

```
class ChapterImages(models.Model):
    chapter = models.ForeignKey('Chapter', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/' + chapter.book.name + '/chapter')
```

The code in the last field of the `ChapterImages` field `image` is wrong. And I want to know if it's even possible to get the name of the parent while creating the child? This is so I can upload it easily to the same folder as the book itself in a sub-folder for that chapter.

As you can see I typed in `chapter.book.name` which wont work(right?). Is there a good way to change this so it can work fine without having to do it manually trough the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really a question about `upload_to`. That attribute also takes a callable, which is passed the instance and the filename:

```
def upload_to_book_path(instance, filename):
    return 'uploads/' + instance.chapter.book.name + '/chapter/' + filename

class ChapterImages(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=upload_to_book_path)
```

Comment: I take it I also have to do /chapter/ + filename at the end? Cause that worked for me! Thanks.